# Multi Application Server

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

Hey does anyone have an architecture or idea of how they deployed more than one application server and database server for Joomla? We are looking to scale to a couple hundred thousands users a day and 1 app, 1 db server just can't quite cut it and let alone we need to keep our SLA high. So what I was thinking was having a load balancer (to start) across an active-active setup of applications servers. For the DB server I was going to have an active-passive setup.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

My recommondation would be to use aws.amazon.com.  You mention a single app, so you'll likely want to offer a robust front-end that uses a scalable database.

AWS offers the ability to load-balance traffic as well as geo-distribute your load so that Europe users don't get San Fran data sources.

On the database side, you can create several different layers of load sharing on mysql databases, such as read-specific instances, failover, and concurrent masters.  It really depends on what you're looking to do.  Because how you handle "an app" and "a website" are entirely different beasts.

Here is an intro to hosting websites (which no mater what you call a Joomla/MySQL deployment, it is a website): http://aws.amazon.com/websites/

Also, AWS has excellent support, just ask them the best way to do what you're looking to do.